# Excepting errors dont except and only summon new erros

Tags: python, try-catch, except

Im tryina to except the error

```
  File ".py", line 656, in raise_transaction_not_found
    raise TransactionNotFound(message)
web3.exceptions.TransactionNotFound: Transaction with hash: '0xb5f2ffa5e1d79e7cf5bee4892f75303db227554c322fa32c1e97026915b740a8' not found.
```

and of course i tried different methods like:

```
except TransactionNotFound as error:
        print('123', error)     
except web3.exceptions.TransactionNotFound as error:
        print('321', error)     
except Exception as error:
        if error == f'Transaction with hash: \'{tx_hash}\' not found.':
            print('123123s')
```

and what would u think? nothing works and 1st exception was `NameError: name 'TransactionNotFound' is not defined`
i have no way how to fix it or maybe i dont understand something

Comment: You need to import that particular exception or create it yourself, you can't just magically call it out

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party library I will suggest you to search on their code base or just google it and find where the exception lives and then just import it at the top of your script:



from some_library.exceptions import TransactionNotFound

Comment: @Kushim that's what they did... the issue is the first `except`, apparently that name is not defined as suggested by the error, so simply remove that first `except TransactionNotFound:` block and leave the rest, because the second `except` there excepts that specific error

Comment: What happens when you use the second except? or the third one? does it enters your statement?

Comment: @Matiiss i have tried each of exceptions one at a time and nothing works

Comment: @Kushim in 2nd exception "AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'exceptions'" appears

Comment: look at the docs where they mention error handling, although seemingly `web3` could be also not the module?

Comment: I just tried **from web3.exceptions import TransactionNotFound** and gave me no error whatsoever

Comment: oh i did as @Kushim said (from some_library.exceptions import TransactionNotFound) and everything works like a charm. big thanks!!

Comment: Can you please upvote the comment so that people know that solves it? :)

Comment: i cant find how to do it maybe because i just registered
i only can report comments haha